# OOP classes and external lists of data

Tags: php, oop, mapping

When programming OO in PHP i never know exactly how to map a class to simple lists of data. I will try to make a simple example wich i am running into every day:

First the MySQL table creates:

```
/* create product table */
CREATE TABLE `product` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `price` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 `brand` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `deliverytime` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

/* data list for all kind of brands */
CREATE TABLE `brand` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

/* brand data*/
insert  into `brand`(`id`,`brand`) values (1,'nike'),(2,'adidas'),(3,'diesel'),  (4,'dkny'),(5,'lacoste');

/* data list for deliverytime */
CREATE TABLE `deliverytime` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deliverytime` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

/* deliverytime data */
insert  into `deliverytime`(`id`,`deliverytime`) values (1,'1 day'),(2,'2 days'),(3,'3 days'),(4,'4 days'),(5,'5 days'),(6,'6 days'),(7,'1 week'),(8,'1 - 2 weeks'),(9,'2 - 3 weeks'),(10,'4 - 5 weeks');
```

**Then** i create the product class.

```
  class Product{
    private 
    $name,
    $description,
    $price,
    $brand
    $deliverytime;

    public function __construct(){
       // etc etc
    }

    public function save(){
       // save the product
    }
   }
```

**Now the big question(s) are:**

How should i handle $brand and $deliverytime in my Product class? 
Should i make a Brand and DeliveryTime object (wich in turn are responsible for fetching the right brand and or deliverytime data)?

And what about saving the Product object? 
How should i handle the brand and deliverytime data?

What is the beste practice or pattern to handle this kind of situations?

Sorry for this noobish question but i wasnt sure where to look for (tags to search for) :/

**EDIT:**

Ok lets say i dont want to use somekind of ORM framework (Doctrine, dORM, redbean etc) since it would be a gigantic overkill for my little system + i am realy want to know how to create the mapping myself for learning purposes... any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the repository pattern for handling your CRUD operations.

Comment: You may also look at Doctrine. It abstracts database interactions in an object-relational matter ;) http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is a style I like to use

```
class ProductModel {
    public function find($id) {
         // fetch product with your database code using parameters to filter

         $product = new ProductEntity(
             // initialize with non foreighn values (eg. $row->id, $row->name)
             new ProductBrandEntity($row->brand_id, $row->brand_name); // available because you joined brand??
             new ProductDeliveryTime(/* initialize */)
         );

         return $product;
    }
}
```

I like to call the object from the database Entities but you can call them whatever you want.. It's basically what you suggested in your question but i prefer to have a Model (from MVC) to initialize the entities and not the entities initializing themselves. You should do some research on ORMs and ActiveRecord because this work has basically already been done for you!

Comment: What is exactly the advantage from having a model initializing (instantiating) the db entities and not having the entities initializing themselves? Is it because the model acts as somesort of factory?

Comment: Sorry for slow response. Yes it acts as a type of factory. In an ideal situation you could have different models for different sources. In my case I have an entity for an internet stream called a StreamEntity and it can be retreived from a StreamApiModel or StreamPdoModel

Comment: Btw TFennis, i have been looking a lot for activerecord. Activerecord is indeed the thing i am trying to create but there doesnt seem to be a good tutorial wich describes how to implement 1:N or N:M relations (associations) in an activerecord object. Do you happen to know any good tuts or articles? I ran into www.phpactiverecord.org but i think its a bit hard to fully understand there code :O